# don't display repeated products in the chekout page React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to create a checkout page, and I've used Context to display the product choosing and display it on the checkout page, but the problem is I can't figure out how to stop repeating the product dupl

```js
//productData is all the products objects passed to this constante every time we click on buy Now
{productData.map(( item,i )=> (<> {for(let j = i+1; j <= productData.length; j++){

                    }}
                    <Grid  item xs={12}  style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between',alignContent:'center', padding:'20px' }}>
                    <Typography style={{ paddingTop:'10px'}} variant='h6'>${item.price * item.numeroProd} </Typography>
                    <Typography variant='h6' style={{textAlign:'center', paddingTop:'10px' }}>{item.title} </Typography>
                    <Badge badgeContent={item.numeroProd} color='secondary'>
                        <img style={{width:'60px', height:'60px'}} src={item.image}/>
                        </Badge>
                        
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough using the map function without using for loop inside the map function because the map function will return something as many as the length of the original value.

In this case productData.map() will return something as many as the length of productData.

So I think the answer is:

```js
{
    productData.map((item, i) => (
        <Grid  item xs={12}  style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between',alignContent:'center', padding:'20px' }}>
            <Typography style={{ paddingTop:'10px'}} variant='h6'>${item.price * item.numeroProd} </Typography>
            <Typography variant='h6' style={{textAlign:'center', paddingTop:'10px' }}>{item.title} </Typography>
            <Badge badgeContent={item.numeroProd} color='secondary'>
                <img style={{width:'60px', height:'60px'}} src={item.image}/>
            </Badge>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

If you want to return a list of values (like strings, numbers, or objects), use "{}" for the map function. Example:

```js
productData.map((item, i) => {
    return item
})
```

If you want to return a list of views (like divs or custom components), use "()" for the map function. Example:

```js
productData.map((item, i) => (
    <div>{item}</div>
))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my problem is to filter the duplicated object products, if it's a duplicate I don't want it to show up in the checkout again, just getting updated in the number of product, the for loop I've attempt to use it to do a if statement but it didn't work, I've forget to remove it!